# Safari 11 Preview: Inspect Element on device without using Develop Menu

Tags: ios, safari

The Safari 11 beta 6 Web Inspector has a feature I want: the ability to retain items in the network tab after navigating to the next page. Unfortunately, it also appears to have a bug: it can no longer find "inspectable applications" in the devices area of the Develop menu. Same problem with Safari Technology Preview Release 38.

For Safari windows on the Mac, that's not a problem; I can control-click and Inspect Element and I'm in business. But for troubleshooting pages on a device, I'm hosed -- this was the only way I knew to open up the Web Inspector against an external device.

This isn't a problem of losing the "Web Inspector" setting on my phone (that's still checked), and as you can see in the photo, even the desktop browser itself doesn't show the currently open windows.

[image: missing inspectable Safari windows]